# Can IndexBar on Sencha touch 1 or 2 to support grouping by date-time?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I dont sure I can use IndexBar to grouping another data except letter (maybe date-time). If can please help to some code sample.

Thanks,

** I think its look like "Color for Facebook" or "Glancee" iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing the [letters](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.IndexBar-cfg-letters) configuration into the `indexBar` config in list:

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {
        var list = Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '{name}',
            grouped: true,
            indexBar: {
                letters: ['1', '2', '3']
            },
            store: {
                grouper: {
                    groupFn: function(record) {
                        return record.get('series');
                    }
                },
                data: [
                    { name: 'episode one', series: '1' },
                    { name: 'episode two', series: '1' },
                    { name: 'episode three', series: '1' },
                    { name: 'episode one', series: '2' },
                    { name: 'episode two', series: '2' },
                    { name: 'episode one', series: '3' },
                    { name: 'episode two', series: '3' },
                    { name: 'episode three', series: '3' },
                    { name: 'episode four', series: '3' }
                ]
            }
        });
    }
});
```